# Virtuemart is great, but how about its code and architecture?

Tags: model-view-controller, refactoring, joomla, virtuemart

Virtuemart is the most popular e-commerce component for Joomla 1.5, the editor selected, total free and open source, with stunning strong power! So great, i like it. Thanks all the developers of Virtuemart.

But, my God, there is SQL query even in its themes, why, and why didn't Virtuemart coordinate MVC architecture of Joomla, and, seems no interest in re-factor to do that. It's so hard to develop base on Virtuemart.

I think there must be some great reasons in the hands of Virtuemart developers, Could anyone tell me the reasons or what the advantage of the architecture of Virtuemart ?

(Also i has the same problems with kunena, the great forum component.)

Comment: I'am sorry, i had some mistakes with kunena 1.6.3 now, she has a beautiful new start in life from v1.6.3. I just saw its update,  the v1.5.x had been refactored ! Thank you,  the persons behind kunena.

Comment: VM has a new MVC release already in beta that addresses all of these issues. If you can't wait for the new release, you can use K2Mart, which is a great extension that combines VM with K2 solving many of the display and front end issues related to VM.

Answer (score 0):

Virtuemart is a eCommerce component for joomla and to handle commercial you have to keep everything secure. Thats why we store everything in database rather storing things temporary.
MVC architecture also helps in re usability of the code with higher security.